# Angular animated ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, ionic-framework

I am using Angular 1.4. I have a list of elements, built using ng-repeat, that can be slided to be removed.

I am looking for a way to use ng-enter, ng-move and ng-leave to do pretty animations when one element is removed.

I found examples but they all uses animations on height, so the result has a poor performance on mobile (I use Ionic). For a good performance of animations, we usually use animations on the "transform" CSS attribute.

But my elements have different heights.

Could you help me with that please? I am stuck for several hours...

Comment: Check out this page: http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/3d-cube-css-transition-animation

Comment: This does not work with Angular 1.4 :(

Comment: Well...I think it's very easy to copy all properties and add efect.ng-enter. The hard part which is to create the effect is done

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The thing is the animation is done on the "height" element, which I cannot do because my elements are complex divs of different heights, and changing the height of a div obfuscates its content. But I finally managed to get the desire effect with a combination of CSS, Angular and jQuery... Pretty ugly but it works.